# How to create custom sink and producer in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I wanted to create takeWhileInclusive operator in RxSwift by composing new sink and producer similar to the way the original takeUntil is created. But I cannot import Sink and Producer classes. What is the proper way of this?